# How to create an alias in MAC OS that can open a URL in terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, alias, zsh

I made an alias that

zsh

```
alias google="open https://www.google.com/s\?wd\="
```

and then

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ google test
```

But Chrome has not been called and it prints

```
The file /Users/a2014/test does not exist
```

So , how can I only write `alias` and call google by cli ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with aliases, because there is no way to concatenate your argument `test` with whatever came from alias expansion. Your final command line is:

```
open https://www.google.com/s\?wd\= test
```

(notice the space before `test`), which asks OS X to open `https://www.google.com/s\?wd\=` and `test` with respective default applications.

Use a function instead:

```
google() {
  open "https://www.google.com/search?q="$1
}
google test
# => opens https://www.google.com/search?q=test
```

Answer (score 3):

Kudos to @Amadan!

A slight improvement that is a bit unwieldy as a comment, else I would have done it that way. Anyway, you may want to url-encode the question so you can do things like this with spaces etc...

```
google "who is mr obama?"
```

in which case you could use:

```
google() {
   encoded=$(php -r "echo rawurlencode('$1');")
   open "https://www.google.com/search?q=$encoded"
}
```